# Discord.js Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
let StaffPerms = false;
        let server = client.guilds.cache.get('737183847816364042')
        let member = server.members.cache.get(message.author.id)
        if(member.roles.cache.has('823136963246424064') == true){
            console.log("PERFECT")
        }
```

This keeps happing and I have no idea why. Each message that comes through this part of code is in DM's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object. You're trying to fetch a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) using the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) id instead of the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) id and so it returns `undefined`. You could use [`Guild#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) to get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object but it will only work if the member is cached. A better solution would be to use [`GuildMemberManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch).

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('737183847816364042')
const member = await guild.members.fetch(message.author)
if (member.roles.cache.has('823136963246424064')) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: This stopped the first error but now I'm getting
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Comment: @WillieWoo257986 Looks like the `message` does not come from a guild. Are you testing in a DM channel?

Comment: Yep! I did say that in the original message.

Comment: @WillieWoo257986 Ah, my bad. Missed that part. Let me update my answer.

Comment: While I'm getting no errors it now sends me down the !member statement.

Comment: @WillieWoo257986 Looks like the user is not part of the guild. Make sure the user is added to the guild and that the guild id used in the code is right.

Comment: I can confirm that I am in the guild. (I'm currently testing it)

Comment: Doing console.log(guild.name) brings the correct name proving this.

Comment: @WillieWoo257986 Looks like the member isn't cached. Just updated my answer.